# How to replace html code in jquery img click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm new to jquery.I tried to load gallery when click image in script. I want to replace images src links when click the top images.

like this-->

image1  image2 image3

if image1 click load gallery1, if image2 click load gallery2 lick vice.

this is the my html code

```
<div>
<img id="book1" src="image1.jpg">
<img id="book2" src="image2.jpg">
</div>

<div id="pages">
<div style="background: url(1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div style="background: url(2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div style="background: url(3.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div>
```

i want to replace this

```
<div id="pages">
    <div style="background: url(1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div style="background: url(2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div style="background: url(3.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div>
```

into

```
<div id="pages">
    <div style="background: url(new1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div style="background: url(new2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div style="background: url(new3.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div>
```

i just want to replace the html
Can anyone help me to write this jquery?

Comment: Create a fiddle for it .http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: where is gallery you want to load ?

Comment: it like a look book. so i want to replace that pages div with new pages2 div

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
<div id="demo">
<img id="book1" src="image1.jpg" class="image1">
<img id="book2" src="image2.jpg" class="image2">
<img id="book3" src="image3.jpg" class="image3">
</div>
<div id="pages">
<div id="image1" style="background: url(1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div id="image2" style="background: url(2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div id="image3" style="background: url(3.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div>
```

javascript ->

```
$(document).on("click","#demo img",function(){
 var  $self= $(this);
 selfId = '#' + $self.attr('class'),
 $("#pages").replaceWith($("#"+selfId) );
});
```

example:http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, where you can add data attribute `data-gallary` to images and its value equal to id of the page `div`. Add `id` to the page `div` as shown below.

Now you need to hide and show pages on the basis of clicked image.

**NOTE** - please make sure that all `id`s should be unique through out the HTML.

HTML:

```
<div>
<img id="book1" src="image1.jpg" data-gallary="page1">
<img id="book2" src="image2.jpg"  data-gallary="page2">
</div>

<div id="pages">
<div id="page1" style="background: url(1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div id="page2" style="background: url(2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div id="page3" style="background: url(3.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('img[id^=book]').click(function(){
   //hide all pages
   $('div[id^=page]').hide();
   //show corresponding page
   var pageId= $(this).data('gallary');
   $('#'+pageId).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: i want to replace <div id="pages">
<div id="page1" style="background: url(1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div id="page2" style="background: url(2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div id="page3" style="background: url(3.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div> this with new code like this with diffrent images

Comment: can you please share a jsfiddle link with your problem statment. And from where you are getting new images, are they available in html code or you are getting them dynamically/

Comment: i used this in Joomla module.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcu5z15h/1/)

Simple jQuery code

```
$("#book1").click(function(){
  $('#page1').attr('src','http://placehold.it/350x150.gif');
  $('#page2').attr('src','http://placehold.it/150x150.gif');
  $('#page3').attr('src','http://placehold.it/100x100.gif');
});

 $("#book2").click(function(){
  $('#page1').attr('src','http://placehold.it/300x300.gif');
  $('#page2').attr('src','http://placehold.it/150x150.gif');
  $('#page3').attr('src','http://placehold.it/100x100.gif');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to alter the img src, you can use this.

You can try $("#book1").attr("src",[your new src]);

If you want to do it on click...

```
$("#book1").click(function(){
    $("#book1").attr("src",[your new src]);
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: can't i change css using this?

Comment: can i replace this <div style="background: url(1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div style="background: url(2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div style="background: url(3.jpg); width:100%;"></div> with <div style="background: url(11.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div style="background: url(12.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div style="background: url(13.jpg); width:100%;"></div>

Comment: Yes. Use $("#book1").css("background-image:");